# What does 'worn smooth' mean?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I am reading an article on this [link](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2020-05-19-what-the-witcher-3-got-right), and in one part, it says 'patterns of thought and movement worn smooth with use'. I searched, and couldn't find a definition for 'wearing smooth'. Does it mean 'getting better'?

Comment: 'This nailfile has worn smooth' uses a resultative construction, the adjective 'smooth' telling us of the state of the file after much wear. Compare 'The well has run dry.'

Comment: This is a transitive resultative construction `Verb + Obj + Adj`, as in _rub it raw, hold it together, paint it green_. The verb _wear_ can be transitive, but _worn_ is a past participle and shows that Passive has applied, so the object has become the subject. _Patterns of thought and movement_ is the object of active transitive _wear_, and the subject of passive intransitive _(be) worn_. Active or passive, the wear is the same, so it's smooth either way.

Answer (score 4):

Your interpretation of it is quite close. In this case the writer is showing that he prefers to do things that he has done before.

> "Patterns of thought worn smooth with use" is applying a physical descriptor to a non-physical thing.

> "To wear smooth" means that an action has occurred so many times that the rough edges have been destroyed [Lexico 2.2](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wear), similar to how [sea glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_glass) forms.

However, he's using this as a positive, in the sense that rather than being destroyed, it has become comfortable, familiar, like a well-used path. So, in the end, he's just referring to methods of game play and game logic that he is already extremely familiar and comfortable with.

Comment: And in this case, *worn smooth* is being used metaphorically.